# Задача на признак делимости на 11. C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Условие [задачи](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=357):

> Для делимости числа на 11 необходимо, чтобы разность между суммой
> цифр, стоящих на четных местах, и суммой цифр, стоящих на нечетных
> местах, делилась на 11.
>
> Требуется написать программу, которая проверит делимость заданного
> числа на 11.
>
> **Входные данные**
>
> Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит одно натуральное число N, делимость
> которого надо проверить (1 ≤ N ≤ 10^10000).
>
> **Выходные данные**
>
> В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите “YES”, если число делится на 11,
> или “NO” иначе.

Сразу оговорюсь. Сайт позволяет делать обычный ввод и вывод без использования файловых потоков.

Решение:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long even = 0, odd = 0;
    string inp;
    cin >> inp;
    int size = inp.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
        even += inp[i] - '0';
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i += 2)
        odd += inp[i] - '0';
    cout << (even - odd % 11 ? "NO" : "YES");
}
```

На одном из тестов программа проваливается (тесты мне не видны). И в действительности мне даже не понятно, почему моя программа проваливается.

> Переполнение?

хорошо рассмотрим число 10^1000 - 1, это число состоит из 9999 девяток. на каждую переменную odd и even идет примерно поровну распределение девяток. но в случае нечетности количества цифр odd перевешивает. значит в крайнем случае odd = 9*(9998/2 + 1) = 45000. Я от страха поставил long long, но очевидно мне это не помогло.

> Переполнение переменных цикла?

size_t range = 2^16 - 1, а по факту мне 1000 уже достаточно, потому что длина строки до 10^1000

> Может надо было условие odd - even, а не even - odd?

Мое условие требует ненулевой остаток и в этом случае мое условие верно. Даже если остаток и будет отрицателен это никак не повлияет на работу.

И вообще я полностью убежден в верности своего решения. От отчаяния я решил проверить ее работоспособность на числах до 10e7. И все срабатывало вполне адекватно.

Я вообще потом подумал, что может выделение строки - плохая затея. Поэтому я решил сделать второе решение. Которое вообще не рабочее по, тоже, не понятным мне причинам.

Второе решение:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long even = 0, odd = 0;
    char x, i = 0;
    while ((x = cin.get()) != EOF)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            even += x - '0';
        else
            odd += x - '0';
        i++;
    }
    cout << (even - odd % 11 == 0 ? "YES" : "NO");
}
```

Вероятно я упускаю какой-то частный случай. Но вторая программа точно работает как-то криво. Объясните мне пожалуйста, что я упускаю и что я сделал не так в своих программах.

Comment: `even - odd % 11` - это точно то, чего Вы хотели? `-` имеет более низкий приоритет, чем `%`.

Comment: @isnullxbh да, вы правы. мне нужно `(even - odd) % 11`, спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все гораздо проще.
Вам дают строку с завершающим переводом строки... `cin.get()` его читает.

Вот решение которое проходит тесты:

```
#include <iostream>
int s;
char a;

int main(){
    while(std::cin>>a)
    {
        s+=a;
        s-=std::cin>>a?a:'0';
    }
    std::cout << (s%11 ? "NO":"YES");
}
```

Кстати, как видите, хранить отдельно две суммы ни к чему.

Comment: Да, хранить две суммы, совершенно ни к чему, но проверить символ нужно. Может это не цифра или есть начальные нули, тогда порядок может нарушится

Comment: @ARHovsepyan  По условию у них только цифры, но вот пробельный символ - что-то мне кажется, что по недоразумению - они засунули (дело в том, что `cin.get(a)` длиннее `cin>>a`, а они там помешаны на размере кода). Ну, а с проверками - это же не производственный код, можно проверить с ними и без них и убедиться, что получается...

Answer (score 0):

Если даже не смотреть внимательно, то:

Ваша программа вводит символы, а эти символы могут быть любыми, в том числе в начале могут быть нули или может быть введен не цифра. Поэтому придется проверять является ли первый символ больше или равно символа '1' и меньше или равно '9' или знаком числа '+'(тогда его нужно пропускать) а другие цифры могут быть еще и нулем.

Второе:
Вы используете консольное приложение, где на одной строке могут не вмещаться столько символов (например если хотим ввести число больше чем 10^100 ), а вы практически читаете только первую строку(до символа '\n'), а значит не всю цифру, а во втором примере читаете '\n' тоже, а это еще хуже.

Третье:

Вы два раза проходите по всем символам строки, когда за один раз можно все делать: